# Python Less/Greater than issue

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, equation

I've been trying to write this program and searching for fixes/answers for this issue. I'm new to writing Python.

```
BatPower = "100"

if BatPower >= "70":
    print("BatPower - GOOD")
elif BatPower <= "50":
    print("BatPower - OK")
elif BatPower <= "30":
    print("BatPower - CRITICAL")
else:
    print("CRITICAL ERROR READING BATPOWER!")
```

So as you can see 'BatPower = "100"' but instead of returning the value "BatPower - GOOD" it returns "BatPower - OK". Also when I input 'BatPower = "2"'. It returns "BatPower - OK"

Here are some other inputs with there outputs:

```
BatPower = "75"
BatPower - GOOD

BatPower = "30"
BatPower - OK

BatPower = "29"
BatPower - OK

BatPower = "99"
BatPower - GOOD

BatPower = "1"
BatPower - OK
```

As you can see, I never get the CRITICAL output. The GOOD output works well until it gets to 100.

EDIT:
**Final working code:**

```
BatPower = 60
BatStatus = "Passing..."

if BatPower >= 70:
    BatStatus="BatPower - GOOD"
elif BatPower >= 30:
    BatStatus="BatPower - OK"
elif BatPower >= 0:
    BatStatus="BatPower - CRITICAL"
else:
    BatStatus="CRITICAL ERROR READING BATPOWER!"

print(BatStatus)
```

**Thank's for helping!**

Comment: Don't use a string to specify the power - Python cannot compare strings like that. Use a number instead

Comment: Strings are compared [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), so e.g. `'100' < '2'`.

Comment: @MartinPieters: the OP has another issue that isn't about the string comparisons. The logic of the program doesn't look like it'll ever return CRITICAL, because any number `n<=30` also satisfies `n<=50`, which is evaluated first. I would like to address that issue in an answer please.

Comment: Here is the answer to the logic problem where critical is never the output. Because `n <= 30` also satisfies `n <= 50`, and because you evaluate `n <= 50` first, you will always get back OK as the answer. I have posted a Github gist that should help you: https://gist.github.com/ericmjl/d8650e4337a3ddf40fd3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major issue, as noted by the other posters, is that you're trying to compare strings as if they were numbers, which is going to fail because of how string comparison operates (one character at a time, starting from the left). Even though `100 > 70` is true, `"100" > "70"` is not; the character `7` is greater than the character `1`.

What you need to do is change everything to integers, perhaps by wrapping the string in the `int()` function. But once you do that, there's still a flaw in your code. Let's walk through an example with `BatPower = 25`.

```
if BatPower >= 70:
```

Nope, `25 >= 70` is not true. Next line:

```
elif BatPower <= 50:
```

This does evaluate to true, since `25 <= 50`. At every step, you want `>=` instead of `<=`, for that reason. That will solve the other problem.

Comment: The OP assigned `"100"` to `BatPower`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, but he's asking about scenarios where he assigned it other values.

Comment: But `BatPower` is *not an integer*, which is the whole point.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is true, hence the edit to my answer. But even if he converted everything to integers, he would still have the issue above.

Comment: Sure, but it's a secondary problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair enough. I changed it and made it a secondary answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm an idiot... I was looking at it in a different way. I've also modified the code to allow me to pass the code.

Comment: I've added the final working code to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Strings compare "lexicographically".   In other words, it compares the first character, then the second, then the third ...

If ever one of the characters is "greater than" the other, then that sets the comparison for the whole string.  So,

```
"100" < "20"
```

is actually `True` because `"1" < "2"`.

The take-away is this -- If you're going to compare numerical data, use numbers instead of strings.  It'll make your life much easier -- e.g.:

```
BatPower = 100

if BatPower >= 75:
    print("BatPower - GOOD")
```